# Per-Episode Original Air Dates for Early 1980s Anime (Golion, Dairugger)

Tags: anime-history, beast-king-golion, armored-fleet-dairugger

I'm looking for a reliable source of information about the original air dates of the individual episodes of two 1980s anime programs: *Beast King Golion* (百獣王ゴライオン H) and *Armored Fleet Dairugger XV* (機甲艦隊ダイラガーXV フィフティーン).

Wikipedia lists what are purported to be original air dates of the first and last episodes of each program (March 4, 1981 – February 24, 1982 for *Golion*, and 3 March 1982 – 23 March 1983 for *Dairugger*), but I'd like to know the original air dates of *every* episode of each program, and I'd like to be reasonably confident that the information is complete and accurate. (Anyone can edit Wikipedia, and I don't know how reliable other online sources might be.)

Does anyone know how I might obtain this information? If it matters, I am in no way fluent in Japanese.

Comment: The ja.wikipedia page for [_Golion_](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%99%BE%E7%8D%A3%E7%8E%8B%E3%82%B4%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AA%E3%83%B3#.E6.94.BE.E9.80.81.E3.83.AA.E3.82.B9.E3.83.88) has a table of airdates; col 1 is episode #; col 2 is the airdate. Likewise for [_Dairugger_](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A9%9F%E7%94%B2%E8%89%A6%E9%9A%8A%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A9%E3%82%AC%E3%83%BCXV#.E5.90.84.E8.A9.B1.E3.83.AA.E3.82.B9.E3.83.88). Should be easy to interpret even without knowing Japanese. I don't know anything about these shows, so I can't speak to the veracity of this information.

Comment: "1981年3月4日" means "year 1981, month 3, day 4" = "March 4, 1981", and so forth. Generally speaking, Japanese Wikipedia has proven to be an accurate source of information for anime topics I'm familiar with, so I would be inclined to believe that this information is correct as well.

Comment: @senshin, although I would prefer a more reliable source than Wikipedia, I'm super-impressed by the level of detail on the pages that you provided links for. Thank you for replying!